# Where is the phpunit.php file?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, phpunit

I'm trying to set up Eclipse to be able to debug PHPUnit tests. I'm trying to follow the [instructions here](http://pkp.sfu.ca/wiki/index.php/Configure_Eclipse_for_PHPUnit#Configure_PHPUnit_as_Run.2FDebug_Configuration).  It says to set up a new Run Configuration, and choose PHP script, and the php file should be phpunit.php

My problem is, I can't find that file anywhere! Does the new version of PHPUnit not come with such a file? How else can you debug the unit tests?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps that file is the equivalent of a tests/AllTests.php test suite? More information on test organization can be found in the manual: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/organizing-tests.html

Comment: @olleolleolle I looked on that page, I don't see any AllTests.php documentation? do you mean to put all my tests in one php file?

Comment: Ah, my search-fu is weak, but Kristian from Copenhagen shows what the AllTests.php is for in his blog post about PHPUnit: http://kristiannissen.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/zend-doctrine-and-phpunit/ It's a single file that kicks off all the other tests.

Comment: @olleolleolle can you post that as an answer so i can accept? seems to be what i was looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that the IDE is looking for is a single file that can run all the tests. One convention in the PHPUnit community is to call that file AllTests.php.

[Kristian from Denmark](http://kristiannissen.blogspot.se/2009/05/zend-doctrine-and-phpunit-great.html) explains this in an article that covers more than that.

Hope this helps!